# Accurate way to determine the distance between lines in a spectrum

Tags: experimental-physics, diffraction, interferometry

I will be doing an experiment where we superimpose Edser-Butler fringes with the spectrum from a mercury lamp. We will be using exact fractions method to determine the distance between de plates in etalon. For this I will need to measure, as accurate as possible, the distance between mercury´s spectrum lines and EB fringes. Any one has an idea of how  to measure this other than directly place a ruler? How can I improve mi measurements.

Comment: I would fit the spectral line with a Gaussian distribution and determine centroid from that.